# Can you choose the role with the "New Assignment" event?

Tags: pandemic, pandemic-on-the-brink

In Pandemic: On The Brink there are several new event cards.  We are curious as to whether the "New Assignment" card lets you choose, or whether you pick one at random (as at the start of the game).

As a follow up question, the card suggests that any player may swap their role with the unused roles, does this mean each in turn gets the opportunity, or any one player?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can play it on any player (not just yourself) at any time.  That **one** player is then allowed to choose a specific role from the available ones.

The thread [here](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/thread/445335/assignment-change) has the game's designer clarifying that it is intended to only affect a single player.  He doesn't specifically comment about choosing versus random, but since earlier people mention choosing and he doesn't correct them, it seems this is the correct interpretation.

This makes the card quite powerful, but choosing a random role would be too weak (you're just as likely to get something less suited to your current situation), and allowing everyone to switch roles would be ridiculously overpowered.